# How can I replace torch tensor's value inplace?

Tags: python, torch

I have some data like this:

```
tensor([0.0872, 0.4737, 0.0954])
```

and I would like to change it to

```
tensor([0,0,0])
```

wherever the value is greater than 0 I assign 0, and wherever the value is less than 0 I assign 1.

I guess there might be an one-line code like lamda x to handle this but I am new to Python and PyTorch so don't really know how to do it.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import torch


def  check_data(data):
    threshold = 0

    # Use boolean indexing to get the indices where the values are greater than the threshold
    indices_greater = data > threshold

    # Use the torch.where() function to replace the values
    data[indices_greater] = 0
    data[~indices_greater] = 1

    print(data) # tensor([1., 0., 1.])


data = torch.tensor([0.0872, 0.4737, 0.0954])
check_data(data)
data = torch.tensor([-0.0872, -0.4737, -0.0954])
check_data(data)
```

[image: An Example]